# [Solved] Problem getting startet with irobot_create_2_1 in Python

Tags: ros, python, irobot-create-2-1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For my bachelors thesis I am currently getting to know the IRobot Create with a TurtleCore and an Overo Fire COM by Gumstix.
Until now I managed to get an Ubuntu 10.04 running on the Overo COM and installed ROS Diamondback and the Browndrivers from the repositories (with apt-get).

I created a new ROS-Workspace in my home directory and started a new package (as described in the Tutorials on the ROS-Wiki).
In my new node (written in Python) I import the Messages and Services published by the irobot_create_2_1 driver with "from irobot_create_2_1.srv import *" and "from irobot_create_2_1.msg import SensorPacket".

When I try to run my program I get the following error:

"ImportError: No module named irobot_create_2_1.srv"

What do I have to do so the import won't fail?

UPDATE:
Thanks Lorenz, it's working now (I didn't have the driver as a dependency). As for the turtlebot drivers: Since the Overo Fire uses an ARM-Processor and the brown-drivers are the only binaries available to control the Create on ARM, I was going with this approach. I tried compiling the turtlebot drivers but I had a lot of unmet dependencies and frustrating hours trying to gather them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45985/%5Bsolved%5D-problem-getting-startet-with-irobot_create_2_1-in-python/) by [mind4z](https://answers.ros.org/users/3395/mind4z/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-16**:
The turtlebot drivers are written in python. To use them, you should use at least electric, better fuerte though. But then, getting all dependencies compiled shouldn't be too hard.

**Comment by [mind4z](https://answers.ros.org/users/3395/mind4z/) on 2012-10-16**:
I'm really new to ROS and it's concepts. So after your comment I guess that using the turtlebot drivers doesn't necessarily mean installing the whole turtlebot package. Or am I wrong again?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-16**:
Right. You just need to build the package `turtlebot_node` and its dependencies. That shouldn't be too bad since it mostly depends on standard ros packages. The only non-standard dependency is kdl.

**Comment by [mind4z](https://answers.ros.org/users/3395/mind4z/) on 2012-10-16**:
Ok, so I'm going to try it your way... will open a new question if (most probably) there will be more problems ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you add the package as a dependency in your manifest file? Did you execute `roslib.load_manifest('your_package')` right at the beginning of your python file?

Btw. I suggest to use the turtlebot driver when using an iCreate. The turtle driver is maintained by Willow and well tested.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1